# How to prevent Visual Studio from automatically removing semi-colon from Javascript?

Tags: visual-studio, formatting

Due to company standards I have to keep semi-colon in Javascript when editing .js file in Visual Studio, but when I run auto-format (CTRL+K CTRL+D) they are automatically removed.

I do not see any options, and the extension I have installed are [these][1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ciMbJ.png, they do not look formatting anything.

Could you help me?

Thanks!